# Custom component input did not get the correct value when data passed using parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic3

I tried to pass `page_number` using code

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.page_number = this.navParams.get('page_number'); //in lesson-content.ts
}
```

to:

```
<question page_number="page_number"></question>  // in lesson-content.html
```

but the result of the console return *undefined*.

```
console.log('in_component:'+this.page_number); // From question.ts component
```

When I ran the code without `<question></question>` component, then the result was fine. The problems occur only when I pass the data to component like

```
<question page_number="page_number"></question>
```

What's exactly I need to do to solve these problems? I tried to use `ngOnInit()` on question component, but still not get the solution. Anyone got ideas?

---

**Pages:**

*lesson-content.html:*

```
<ion-content padding>
    <question page_number="page_number"></question>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons start>
            <button ion-button clear icon-only>
                <ion-icon name="tag"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-buttons end>
            <button (click)="continueLesson(page_number)" ion-button class="btn-continue">
                Continue
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

*lesson.ts:*

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import {LessonProvider} from "../../../providers/lesson/lesson";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-lesson-content',
    templateUrl: 'lesson-content.html',
})

export class LessonContentPage {
    public page_number:number;
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private dataLesson: LessonProvider) {

    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.page_number = this.navParams.get('page_number');
    }

    gotoSummary()
    {
        this.navCtrl.push('SummaryPage');
    }

    continueLesson(page)
    {
        page = parseInt(page) + 1;
        console.log('page_'+page);
        if(page > this.dataLesson.getTotalLesson() - 1)
        {
            this.gotoSummary();
        }else
        {
            this.navCtrl.push('LessonContentPage',{page_number:page});
        }
    }

}
```

---

**Components:**

*question.ts:*

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {LessonProvider} from "../../providers/lesson/lesson";

@Component({
    selector: 'question',
    templateUrl: 'question.html',
    inputs: ['page_number']
})
export class QuestionComponent {

    public dataDisplay:any = [];

    @Input()
    page_number:any;

    constructor(public dataQuestion:LessonProvider) {
        console.log('in_component_construct:'+this.page_number);
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        console.log('in_component:'+this.page_number);
        this.dataDisplay = this.dataQuestion.getLessonData(this.page_number)
    }

}
```

*question.html:*

```
<div [innerHTML] = "dataDisplay.content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are syntax errors. Do these changes and try.

*lesson-content.html:*

```
<question [page_number]="page_number"></question>
```

*question.ts:*

```
@Input('page_number')
page_number:any;

questionClick(){
  console.log(this.page_number);
}
```

*question.html:*

```
<div (click)="questionClick()">{{page_number}}</div>
```

Comment: The results still the same.

Comment: I have made some changes in answer. Please try and click on component. Let me know if its printing `pagr_number` in console or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the key as a string may be it works for e.g :-

```
let data = {"page_number": page}
```

Comment: The problem is at component

Comment: Not the pages, I think.